# Distinct on three columns in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a 20 Columns Table which have duplicate value but not in all columns. that what normal distinct clause not working on it..
so i want to apply distinct on three columns (name,fname,dob) , but how? . Please give me any solution .

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` with a common-table-expression(CTE):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,fname,dob ORDER BY name,fname,dob)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

This takes one per group. Change `ORDER BY name,fname,dob` according to your logic.

Comment: You can as well use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` probably.

Comment: @Rahul: but OP wants all columns.